# What is the replacement of JavascriptContext.includeLib in icefaces 4.2

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I have to load an external javascript file on a page. Previously in iceface 1.8 version I was using  JavascriptContext.includeLib to load my script. In 4.2, I have JavascriptRunner but not sure how to use it to load the js file. Is there any other option?